# Does a basis $b$ exist such that only a finite number of palindromes in base $b$ are primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, conjectures, palindrome

Can we prove that a base $b$ must necessarily exist so that only a finite number of palindromes in base $b$ are primes?

My friend came up with this, I hope it isn't one of those ubiquitous "innocent" number theory problems which are years beyond any hope for solution.

So far our ideas have not yielded any fruits:

- The number of palindromes under $n$ is roughly $\sqrt{n}$
- The number of primes under $n$ is roughly $\frac{n}{\log n}$
- Any such prime must have odd length (work $\bmod b+1$)

Comment: According to wikipedia (Palindromic Prime) the number of such  primes, in base 10, is conjectured to be infinite. This may very well be one of those "innocent" killer questions.

Comment: This is probably false if we consider the truth of conjectures such as Bunyakovsky conjecture.

Comment: @Vepir I’d be interested to know which family of conjectures specifically imply this statement.  I think this would make for a good answer.